# Magento SSL - Fonts makes trouble - Please Help!

Tags: theme, ssl, https, fonts

I´ve a problem with the SSL in Magento. Firefox says it blocks some content on the site.

My Blocking Tools says this fonts are blocked:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>*(click screenshot to enlarge)*</sup>

But I can´t find these fonts with the links in my code.

These links are not "https", where can I edit that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the font to your font folder ap path

app/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/web/font/

and call it from typography.less

Why you need to use extarnal links for fonts?

If you want to do it anyway : try to change it to "https"

more information on this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108091/how-could-a-https-site-enable-external-http-link-without-warning-from-browser